using OxyPlot with c# MAUI
Hello I try to use OxyPlot in a c# .NET 8.0 MAUI application but on the UI nothing appears, not even the axes. I've tried to look for examples on the internet but all I could find were Xamarin projects. Thanks for your help in advance.
In the MainPage.xaml I have:
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:OrientationPlotModel x:Key="orientationPlotModel"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

And I have this inside of a Frame:
   <oxy:PlotView x:Name="OrientationDiagramPlotModel" BackgroundColor="White" />
In the MainPage.xaml.cs I have:
private OrientationPlotModel orientationPlotModel;

public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  orientationPlotModel=new OrientationPlotModel();
  OrientationDiagramPlotModel.BindingContext = orientationPlotModel;

}

In the OrientationPlotModel.cs I have:
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Axes;
using OxyPlot.Series;

namespace MauiApp2.View
{
  public class OrientationPlotModel
  {
    public PlotModel PlotModel { get; private set; }

    private LineSeries orientationSeries;

    private double[] orientationData = new double[10];

    public OrientationPlotModel()
    {
      InitializePlotModel();
    }

    private void InitializePlotModel()
    {
      PlotModel = new PlotModel();

      var bottomAxis = new LinearAxis
      {
        Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
        Minimum = 10,
        Maximum = 100,
        Title = "X Axis Title",
        MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, 
        MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
        AxislineColor = OxyColors.Blue,
      };

      var leftAxis = new LinearAxis
      {
        Position = AxisPosition.Left,
        Minimum = 0,
        Maximum = 180,
        Title = "Y Axis Title",
        MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
        MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
      };
      
      PlotModel.Axes.Add(bottomAxis);
      PlotModel.Axes.Add(leftAxis);

      orientationSeries = new LineSeries();

      PlotModel.Series.Add(orientationSeries);

      for (int i = 0; i < orientationData.Length; i++)
      {
        orientationSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, orientationData[i]));
      }
    }

    public void UpdateOrientation(float orientation)
    {
     //...
    }
  }
}


Did oxyplot supported .net8 ?  if not what alternative you used for maui ?
